# How to center two items of unknown dimensions in a box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a 150px square box. I have two items in it. The width and height of the two items is variable and unknown. The first (`.label`) I want to be at the top and centered horizontally. The second (`.image`) I want to be centered both vertically and horizontally.

Here's my attempt using `position: absolute`:  ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkx0qp9h/))

```
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

This almost works, except I don't know the width of the image, so I can't adjust to keep it centered.

My attempt with flex box goes wrong as well:

```
.green {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You want to keep Your `css` then add `transform:translate(-50%,-50%);` for `.image`

There is example :

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.label {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%); /*go back for 50% of image size left and top*/
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <div class="label">
    Label
  </div>
  <div class="image">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/0000ff/ffff00" />
  </div>
</div>
<p>
The image should be centered in the box no matter what the width/height of the image.
</p>
<p>
The label should be centered on the top no matter what its width. Normally I'd do something like <code>margin-left: -$half-of-width</code> but I don't know the width. 
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="label">LABEL</div>
  <div class="box" id="image">IMAGE</div>
</div>
```